# Obtener la suma de cada columna rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, datatable

Quisiera saber como obtener la suma de cada columna que fue generada de la siguiente forma:

```
table_homicidio_d <- final_data %>% 
  filter(tipo_h %in% "HOMICIDIO") %>% 
  group_by(dept_h) %>% 
  summarize(CNMH = sum(CNMH),
            FISCALIA = sum(FISCALIA),
            REINICIAR = sum(REINICIAR),
            LISTA = sum(LISTA),
            OBSERVADOS = length(tipo_h))
```

Al generar el codigo obtengo la siguiente información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quisiera obtener al final la suma de cada variable. Es decir, tener el la fila TOTAL para CNHM, FISCALIA etc..

Intenté con mutate, pero lo que hace es generarme una nueva columna.

Comment: Si qiueres la suma total, quita el agrupamiento, es decir comenta o elimina `group_by(dept_h)`

Answer (score 1):

La función `apply` es muy útil para obtener medidas de resumen de múltiples variables de un data frame. Para calcular las sumas de las columnas, el código es el siguiente:

```
apply(X= table_homicidio_d[-1], MARGIN=2, FUN= sum)
```

En la primera parte del código especificas el data frame que contiene tus variables. En este caso, veo que la primera columna corresponde a una variable de clase  `character`, así que la descarto de la función escribiendo `[-1]`. El siguiente argumento es `MARGIN` y define si la función se aplicará a las filas (`MARGIN= 1`), a las columnas (`MARGIN=2`) o ambas (`MARGIN= c(1,2)`). El argumento `FUN` define el tipo de función que buscas, en este caso la suma `FUN= sum`.

Comment: Una breve explicación de lo que hace tu código mejorará la calidad de tu respuesta y ayudará y ayudará muchos mas usuarios que tienen un problema similar. Saludos ;)

Comment: Gracias Alexis!  Me funcionó